# No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"Account"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My routes file has:

```
  post 'account/create'
```

My view page is in Home#index and looks like:

```
<%= form_for @account, url: { :controller => "Account", :action => "create" }, html: { class: "" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
    <%= f.button "Go" %>
<% end %>
```

My controller has:

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController

  def create

  end
end
```

So my home#index page has a form that should post to account#create, but when I try and render the page I see an error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"Account"}
```

I'm confused why it can't find the route, rake routes shows the route just fine:

```
account_create POST   /account/create(.:format)           account#create
```

Also, can I just use the ruby 1.9 syntax like:

```
controller: "Account", action: "create"
```

Do I put AccountController or just Account ?

thanks!

I'm using the latest version of rails 4.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `account` instead of `Account` as value to `:controller` option:

```
<%= form_for @account, url: { :controller => "account", :action => "create" }, html: { class: "" } do |f| %>
```

Alternatively, you could shorten it by using the named route `account_create` for Account creation:

```
<%= form_for @account, url: account_create_path , html: { class: "" } do |f| %>
```

Comment: strange how it is case sensitive when the controller is Account.

Comment: Your controller is `AccountController`. In your routes Rails router identifies it with `account#create` so you need to pass it as "account".